# Confidence interval of a constant value

Tags: probability, statistics, confidence-interval

If W<sub>1</sub>,W<sub>2</sub>,... are i.i.d with N(0,σ<sup>2</sup>), where σ<sup>2</sup> is unknown. Let X<sub>i</sub> = m + W<sub>i</sub>, where m is some constant. Suppose M<sub>10</sub> = 8.5 and S<sub>10</sub> = 2. Find the 95% confidence interval for m.

What I've tried:

Since the sample mean of W<sub>i</sub> is going to be 0, and since the sample mean of X<sub>i</sub> is 8.5, then the confidence interval is going to be 8.5 $\pm$ (1.96$\frac 2 {\sqrt{10}})$. This isn't the correct answer, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Can someone help me out here?

Thanks

Comment: Since the population variance is unknown, and the sample size is small, you should use Student’s t distribution, instead of the normal distribution. So instead of 1.96, you have to find the right value from the t-distribution, using 9 degrees of freedom. I think it’s 2.262

Comment: Also, you really shouldn’t say that the sample mean of $W_i$ is going to be 0. Instead, say that $X \sim \operatorname{N}(m, \sigma^2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\frac{M_{10} - m}{\sigma/\sqrt{10}} \sim N(0,1)
$$
Therefore
$$
\Pr\left( -1.96 < \frac{M_{10}-m}{\sigma/\sqrt{10}} < 1.96 \right) = 0.95,
$$
and so
$$
\Pr\left(M_{10} - 1.96\cdot \frac \sigma{\sqrt{10}} < m < M_{10} + 1.96 \cdot\frac\sigma {\sqrt{10}}  \right) = 0.95.
$$
But $\sigma$ is unknown.
$$
\frac{M_{10} - m}{S_{10}/\sqrt{10}} \sim t_9
$$
(Student's t-distribution with $9$ degrees of freedom.)
$$
\Pr\left( -2.262 < \frac{M_{10}-m}{S_{10}/\sqrt{10}} < 2.262 \right) = 0.95
$$
$$
\Pr\left( M_{10} - 2.262\cdot \frac {S_{10}} {\sqrt{10}} < m < M_{10} + 2.262\cdot\frac {S_{10}} {\sqrt{10}} \right) = 0.95
$$